# Assign Background Colour to UIView

Tags: uiview, xcode6

I have a colour (42, 61, 68) with HEX Colour # 2A3D44, which I set it in UIView's [background colour property](http://1drv.ms/1EplAUN) in the xib.

I have compared the results with colour meter and it's not what I expected, the colour I got is (32, 47, 51). You can take a look at it yourself [here](http://1drv.ms/1aSMaZW).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Attiqe

Answer (score 0):

Guys my mistake I didn't selected the [Generic RGB](http://1drv.ms/1MerZBq) from the colour dialog.

-A